# How to use date range in IIF function in MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, mdx-query

Am having 2001,2002 and 2003 years of data in the SSAS server.

Without using where clause and filters I need to get the aggregated data using the IIF function in the MDX query for a particular date range.

I have referred to many sites but I didn't find any solutions using date range in the IIF function.

[image]

These are the date values am having, so I need to get aggregated Sales Amount Quota values for a particular date range, for example, 01/07/2002 to 30/11/2002(It is dynamic).  I need to use this date range in the IIF function.

My expected result is to be $24,381,800 for the given date range.

Can anyone please guide me to use the date range in the IIF function in the MDX query?